# How to get clear copy paste data into a form

Tags: php, substr, strpos

I'm not sure if this title is the correct title for this question.
My problem is.. a have a form, which need to be fill in by copy & paste from a document.

The following is my code:

```
// length of rrnNo = 12 character, could be append with spaces and start with spaces as well 
$RRN = $this->input->post('rrnNo');

// do some search using $RRN
$checkRRN = strpos($text, $RRN)

if ($checkRRN !== FALSE)
{
   print $text;
}
```

I hit a bug whereby, when the user copy and paste whole 12 digit, no search results display. But when they copy and paste the last 9 digit, they manage to get the results. So what I did was..

```
// length of rrnNo = 12 character, could be append with spaces and start with spaces as well  
$RRN = $this->input->post('rrnNo');

// get last 9 digits
$shortRRN = substr($rrn,-9);

// do some search using shortRRN
$checkRRN = strpos($text, $shortRRN)

if ($checkRRN !== FALSE)
{
   print $text;
}
```

But still doesn't work with 12 digits. They still need to paste data with 9 digits to get the results. Appreciate your advice/opinion.
Thanks

Comment: what language is this?  please tag the correct language.

Comment: sorry.. its php.. thanks

Comment: This sounds like a client-side issue, nothing to do with PHP. Use your browser's F12 tools to inspect the actual request form-data being sent to your PHP script.

Comment: Also, what library/framework are you using in PHP? `$this->input->post` is not part of PHP's standard library.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `<textarea>` tag in form. If you are facing problem with form .. then please post html contents also. It will get some clarity.

Comment: im using codeigniter as framework.. I believe my form is ok since I manage to capture all data correctly.. i just triggered it after my user use copy & paste into the form and function strpos didn't work correctly.. and weirdly.. it can only read 9 character instead 12..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
$RRN = trim($this->input->post('rrnNo',true));
//trim the string to remove spaces before and after, and the second parameter is for xss handling (security) 

if (strpos(trim($text), $RRN) )
{
   print $text;
}
```

Also, if you want to make sure that the user provides exactly 12 characters, load the `form-validation` library and  do a quick validation like this.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rrnNo',"RNN number",'trim|required|min_length[12]|max_length[12]');
if ($this->form_validation->run()){
  //write your code in here
}
```